# How to call on a Prototype from inside a Hook in a Model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I use Sequelize and in my User model have a hook and a prototype (see below). On the second line of the hook, I try to reference the prototype. But this doesn't work. It returns

> this.getAllUsersInclMembersis not a function

How can I call upon the prototype from inside the hook?

```
module.exports = (sequelize) => {

    User.afterUpdate(async (options) => {
        // here I try to call upon the prototype for the instance
        let users = await this.getAllUsersInclMembers();
        await Promise.all(
            await users.forEach(async (user) => {
                // here we reference to a prototype in another model
                user.syncToDb();
            })
        );
    });

    User.prototype.getAllUsersInclMembers = function {
        return sequelize.models.Product.findAll({
            where: { user_id: this.getDataValue("id") },
        });
    };

};
```

---

*Update:* I've updated the hook to the code below but still with the same result:

```
User.afterUpdate(async function (user, options) {
    // here I try to call upon the prototype for the instance
    let users = await this.getAllUsersInclMembers();
    await Promise.all(
        await users.forEach(async (user) => {
            // here we reference to a prototype in another model
            user.syncToDb();
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: Arrow functions do not have `this`, so you need to use a regular function for the `afterUpdate` callback.

Comment: It's `async (user, options) => {` afaics from the docs

Comment: I've rewritten it as a regular function and added `user` next to `options` (see update OP). I still get the same error though.

Comment: Well then you'll need to use `user.getAllUsersInclMembers` instead of `this.getAllUsersInclMembers` of course

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it:

```
User.addHook("afterUpdate", async function (instance, options) {
    let users = await instance.getAllUsersInclMembers();
    await Promise.all(
        await users.forEach(async (user) => {
            // here we reference to a prototype in another model
            user.syncToDb();
        })
    );
});
```